# How to get window title from it's process path

Tags: c++, winapi, window-handles

I have a path of a process, I would like to get it's window title in C++.

Let's assume that this process has only one window.

So for example my process path is :

C:\Program Files\My Program\program.exe which is a running process's path, and I would like to get it's windows title.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is an executive? If you mean executable then look into api's such as getprocess() getwindowhandle()

Comment: Who says a process has only one window?

Comment: And who says that pocess have at least one window? And there's no two process running at the same time? In any case you can try use EnumWindows for enumerate all windows, or use FindWindow if you know title of window.

Comment: Yes, I mean executable. Let's assume the process has only one window, always. So I should enumerate all windows and somehow I should check their's path?

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope its better now.

Comment: To make your question answer suitable for SO, try one the suggestions in the comments and ask a specific question, one with an error message or some code that does not work like you think it should. The process will reward you more than reputation points ever will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** there is only 1 window in the process, and **assuming** there is only one copy of the executable running at a time, then you can use `EnumWindows()` to enumerate top-level windows, calling `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, `OpenProcess()` and `GetModuleFileNameEx()` on each window to get its owning process's path, and if you find a matching path then you can use `GetWindowText()` to get that window's title and stop the enumeration.